# Can I Conditionally Use More Than 1 Argument?

Tags: c++, parameters, macros, parameter-passing, precompile

So this code works well as an example:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(x) x
#define PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(x) x
#else
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(x) void
#define PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(x)
#endif

int foo(DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(const bool param)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    if(param) {
        cout << "DEBUG true\n";
    } else {
        cout << "DEBUG false\n";
    }
#else
    cout << "RETAIL\n";
#endif
}

int main() {
    foo(PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(true));
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/LWVZvG)

But I want to use this for a second parameter, for example: `int foo(const int param1, DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(const int param2))` Obviously that doesn't work for my current definition of `DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM`, I get the error:

> error: invalid use of type `void` in parameter declaration

Is there some noop parameter type that I can use which would allow this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the C++ FAQ:

> Because `#define` macros are evil in 4 different ways: [evil#1](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros), [evil#2](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-if), [evil#3](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-multi-stmts), and [evil#4](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-token-pasting). Sometimes you should use them anyway, but they’re still evil.

It doesn't make sense to use a macro here. It's simply `#ifdef`ing out code, but requiring the user to look that up. A much better approach would simply be to use an `#ifdef`:

```
int foo(
#ifdef DEBUG
        const bool param
#endif
       );
int foo(const int param1
#ifdef DEBUG
        , const int param2
#endif
       );
```

And to call do the same thing:

```
foo(
#ifdef DEBUG
    true
#endif
   );
foo(13
#ifdef DEBUG
    , 42
#endif
   );
```

This code can be a bit choppy for functions taking a small number of arguments and may be laid out with a `#else` if that is considered more readable:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    int foo(const bool param);
#else
    int foo();
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
    int foo(const int param1, const int param2);
#else
    int foo(const int param1);
#endif
```

The same thing may be done for the calls:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    foo(true);
#else
    foo();
#endif
#ifdef DEBUG
    foo(13, 42);
#else
    foo(13);
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You should include comma into macro and not emit void.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(x) , x
#else
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(x)
#endif
int foo(const int param1 DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(const int param2))
```

or include comma into param, so this macro can be used anywhere:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(...)
#define PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(...)
#endif

int foo1(DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(const bool param)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    if(param) {
        cout << "DEBUG true\n";
    } else {
        cout << "DEBUG false\n";
    }
#else
    cout << "RETAIL\n";
#endif
}

int foo2(int DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(, const bool param)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
    if(param) {
        cout << "DEBUG true\n";
    } else {
        cout << "DEBUG false\n";
    }
#else
    cout << "RETAIL\n";
#endif
}

int main() {

    foo1(PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(true));
    foo2(0 PASS_DEBUG_PARAM(,true));

    return 0;
}
```

[Working code online.](http://ideone.com/GObPP3)

Comment: Yeah, looks like something that handles the comma internally is going to be the only way to do this. But I don't think that is an outright solution cause what if it's the only param. I'm probably going to have to require the user to pass the comma internally as necessary.

Comment: Using `__VA_ARGS__`, you may be able to write
`int foo(const int param1 DECLARE_DEBUG_PARAM(, int param2))`
to handle `foo` with 0 or n parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest some different options.

---

1) Use a default value:

```Cpp
enum class DebugSwitch {No_debug, Debug}

void function(int param1, DebugSwitch debug_param = DebugSwitch::No_debug)
{...}
```

2) use a parameter object

```Cpp
struct Parameters
{
     int param1;
     bool debug_param;
     // ....
};

void function(Parameter& p)
{
     ///...
}
```

Why? You are multipling the amount of possible combinations of values which can be sent to the function;

```Cpp
DEBUG defined + param == true
DEBUG defined + param == false
DEBUG not defined + param == true
DEBUG not defined + param == false
```

To be sure that you're handling all the combinations correctly - reduce the ammount of "steering" variables.